# Why Windows 10 has a svchost process that listen on port 53?

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I believe this starts only recently. When my Windows 10 starts, a `svchost` process will start automatically and listens at port 53.

I noticed this because my `pi-hole` docker container failed to start recently, and I have been using a `pi-hole` container for about a year on the same computer.

I checked the Internet, and I could not find any information about some new Windows 10 feature that acts as a local DNS.

#### Update

Thank you @user1686 for the tip.

By using this command `netstat -ab -p udp`, I found the port is owned by the `SharedAccess` service which name is actually the **Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)** in the `Services` manager and which I believed is started by the `Host Network Service`.

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53             *:*
  SharedAccess
```

But I could not found out why the `Host Newtork Service` suddenly got started. Since it is to "*Provides support for Windows Virtual Networks.*", I guess it is due to some changes in the recent Docker Desktop update which changed how docker containers utilize the Windows network.

Comment: Do you know _which_ service the socket belongs to? (Both netstat and other tools such as Process Hacker should show it.)

Comment: It only shows which process is using the port, which is `svchost`. But I could not find out which *service*.

Comment: Ah...it is `SharedAccess` service which I have no idea what it is...

Answer (score 1):

credits to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/solved-unable-to-stop-internet-connection-sharing/b01e1ebc-4f9d-4bf6-8d15-37a782fa03ff

The key issue is the `Host Network Service`, which, I guess, is required by some Hyper-V services. However, the related service still works even after port 53 is used by other processes.

So to solve this issue:

1. Stop the `Host Network Service` service
2. Stop the `Internet Connection Sharing` service
3. Start your service/process that uses port 53
4. Start the `Host Network Service` service